# Does GOD know future because of kalpa cycle?

Tags: krishna, moksha, vyasa

Sage vyasa said there is nothing like fate, otherwise there is no any meaning of karma, and Lord Krishna said, I know all past and future, so he know that because of kalpa cycle(Which means same thing will repeat after every new kalpa)?

People said yogi and god are beyond time and space, but what is meaning of beyond time, you can only said that when time is in linear form and you're out of that line, but god and yogi living in same line. Time is cyclic, and when yogi predict something, then he may see just past kalpa or chaturyug. And hence [Kak Bhusundi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9118/help-me-solve-the-mystery-of-age-of-yugas-and-lord-vishnus-avatars/11145#11145) says he had seen Ramayan 11 times and Mahabharat (Krishna) 16 times with **different outcomes**...

So here kak bhusandi can also predict like what will happen in the next, because he live on many chaturyuga. Since rama will always kill ravana, but the method and strategy may differ always.

@iammilind and others - If same thing repeat in same pattern, then how we can sure we are living in 28th kaliyuga, or [Sweta varha kalpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13635/10405)? because if same thing repeat in same pattern then how you can't add +1 on it. Yuga, Manvanatara and kalpa have identities with names hence it should not repeat in same pattern. You can say that about maha kalpa, since we don't know how many maha kalpa is passed.

Comment: Knowledge of the future is a sign of a high level of achievement of yoga -basically the transcendence of time. God knows the future because he is yogiswareswara. He is beyond time and space.

Comment: I agree with you that on higher level of yoga, they know everything, but it is practice, and by doing that practice, they might see the past kalpa events and hence [all yogi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10604/10405) know futures.[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10744/10405) is some good points, but still I am confuse on first kapa, because on first kalpa nobody can see the future. So did bramha first test the cycle in 0 kalpa?

Comment: I mean parbraman not bramha who test, first cycle in 0 kalpa and [Trinity are not beyond time and space when new kalpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13636/10405) is created, only parbraman know all things. May be after doing yoga(Sadhna), they know the past kalpa and create same kalpa again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Shiva or Vishnu or Trikaladarshi Yogi know our Aagami Karma or our free will?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/does-shiva-or-vishnu-or-trikaladarshi-yogi-know-our-aagami-karma-or-our-free-wil)

Comment: @iammilind I am using SE from a long time, you've marked the question as duplicate just because I have added the last sentence which is matching with another question, but in reality I have added it because other can understand it perfectly what I am trying to ask, so let me remove it first. Other question said "does they know our future" and my question is does they know our future because of kalpa cycle? there is some difference. I am fine if the question is not answer by anyone, but it's not duplicate for me.

Comment: The other part of your Qn is answered here: [When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20417/1049). Just that I have taken example of Drona's Moksha in the comment section. To answer your Qn in brief, since all the events are predetermined -- all the events will repeat in perfect harmony. If you consider "soul" as "jiva", then same soul will enter Bhishma's body & eventually be liberated. If you consider "soul" as "Atma", then there is no Qn of it getting Moksha as *Atma* is another interpretation of Moksa.

Comment: When you said exactly in same pattern,then have you any reference about that? The BG just said all things will start again and again like in cyclic pattern, but it does not say, it will start again with same pattern. Let me know if you find any scripture which said same thing will happen in **same pattern**. The eternal return is just philosophy which you and Nietzsche agree with that. If the kalpa is same as previous then there is no need to give any kalpa name. Every kalpa name have different story about trinity, did you know about that?

Comment: @iammilind can you please re-open my question, I have edited it. Your two answer speak different things, first check you said all things will repeat in same pattern, then you said [god can't see our aagami karma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10722/10405), why, since you're repeating yourself, so doesn't GOD know what you've done in previous? Let me know if you agree with that, so I can continue.

Comment: *"I am using SE from a long time"* -- then you should know that your Qn is Not closed! :-) I have just proposed 2 Qn-s which are likely to answer your Qn. It's upto the community to decide if they are really duplicates. -- Now, *"so doesn't GOD know what you've done in previous?"* -- What do you call God here? Do you think it's some entity? If yes, then that entity will also repeat with all the events. In reality, no one can know for sure what is going to happen in future, even though the future, present, past are predetermined. There can be predictions though, which are also predetermined.

Comment: The kalpa name is different and the story of every kalpa is also different, then how you can said this is 28th kaliyuga, because even god is also repeating based on your philosophy, so this should be 1st kaliyuga and 1st kalpa, because we are repeating, if everything is pre determine in same pattern then how you can add +1?

Comment: Why are you referring to the monotheist god, since you're talking about Hinduism?

Comment: I mean all GOD(Rama, krishna, Shiva) and yogi(vyas) who can know future.  Sorry if you misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer "God" as a supreme reality (the One), then 'That' is said to be unborn, undying, immutable -- "non-being" (indescribable):

> BG 2.20 - Doesn't born or die at anytime; Neither existed or existing, nor will exist; Unborn, eternal, undecaying, ancient -- 'That' is not hunted, [when] the body is hunted.

All existences (including us) are reflections of that supreme One. But some are closer and some are farther.

> BG 4.7 - Though I am unborn, undecaying by nature, and the Lord of beings, (still) by subjugating My *Prakruti*, I take birth by means of My own *MAya*.

RAma, Krishna, VyAsa are closer reflections. But those are subjected to birth & death. Whatever has a beginning, has certainly an end.

> BG 2.27 - Death is certain for the "born"; Birth is certain for the "dead"; Therefore, what is unavoidable, you don't have to grieve.

So from above, we can deduce that certain divine beings (like RAma, Krishna, VyAsa) are also part of *Prakruti*. *Prakruti* itself has born from the nature of the supreme One.
Though we call it Brahman, Vishnu, Shiva etc. for ease of use -- 'That'  one cannot be named or described; Otherwise it also becomes *Prakruti*, which is describable.

---

> BG 7.26 - O Arjuna, **I know the past and the present as also the future beings; but no one knows Me!**  (here, Me = That)

Hence, if we think that "someone" is supreme (i.e. beyond *Prakruti*), then certainly that "someone" will Not know past, present, future. Because "someone" is describable. That in turn makes that "someone" not supreme at absolute level.
That implies, that "no one" (or nothing) is supreme. Because, Nothing is indescribable. In that case, Yes, "no one" knows past, present, future, as stated above!

<sub>[Note: Above answer is from scripture perspective. From rational perspective, you may refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10722/1049) to understand, how everything repeats, making the past, present, future predetermined, hence unknowable.]</sub>

Comment: I already read your [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10722/1049), and I can't agree with your statement "All things repeat in same pattern". Each yuga,manvanatara and kalpa have different identity, it means the action is also different. Don't you see different story with different kalpa name?

Comment: @Goyllo, if those are just "stories", then they're not worth debating. If they are real events then we have to see their authenticity. Moreover it's quite possible that those *Kalpa*s are finite in number (say 50), and they are repeating infinitely in every cycle (i.e. 1to50-1to50-1to50-...).

Comment: I am not atheist, I don't say it is just stories(Sorry not good in English and can't find alternative word), but look's like you misunderstood me. Even kak bhusandi say I have seen different outcome. And some of old man in my village also said ravana killed by laxman, so it might be true in other satyuga. First understand what I want to trying to say. **Time is cyclic and yugas, manvantara and kalpa are repeated, that's true, but same thing repeat in same pattern which I don't believe on it**. Is 18th and current kaliyuga same? Is past kalpa and current kalpa same?

Comment: You said kalpa are in finite number which is true(1 to 100 or bramha age), so that's what I want to say yugas are repeated in every manvantara, but it's finite, and same 14 manvanatara repeat in one kalpa, which is also finite, and other 100 kalpa repeat in one maha kalpa which is also finite, so how you can say same thing repeat in every kalpa as well? If you said same thing **repeat after maha kalpa** then I can't disagree with you completely, because there is less information available for [maha kalpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21223/10405).

Comment: *"kalpa are repeated, that's true, but same thing repeat in same pattern which I don't believe"*, @Goyllo, "repeat" means same pattern, else it's not repeating. If you believe they repeat, then you ought to believe same pattern. We are not concerned about Kalpa or Mahakalpa, but a cycle. You can name that cycle whatever. The cycle has set of unique events. After all events are finished, it's re-cycled. Try to imagine that we have infinite past; without cyclic events, present moment can't be reached.

Comment: Repeat means same pattern, lol how you can say that? Sunday to money repeat in every weekend, January to December repeat in every year, so the same pattern repeat every week and every year? Time is cyclic that's true, but you understand it repeat in same pattern that's not true. Is 18th kaliyuga(Parashurama killed evil kshatriya) and current kaliyuga same? Same it is for kalpa as well. Kalpa are repeat but same kalpa repeat next time that's not true. Otherwise the soul which achieve moksha will take re-birth again in next kalpa?

Comment: And please don't say kalpa is very long time, it is just 1 day of bramha. And it is same like our day. Even when bramha talking to [Kakudmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi), for a few seconds, then here in the earth passed 27 yugas. So again I have read some of your answer on which you said it is very long time, but in reality it's not. It is more like black hole(If you go from earth to bramhalok), and related to [Einstein theory of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation).