# What are the different outcomes of Mahabharat and Ramayan as seen by KaakBhushandi?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, universe

Kakabhushundi saw Ramayan 11 times with different outcomes and saw Mahabharat 16 times with different results in different universes. Please tell me what are the 11 different outcomes of Ramayan and 16 different outcomes of Mahabharat if the information is available.

Comment: I don't think it is directly available somewhere but still I would request experts here to guess along the broader lines.

Comment: I am both curious and really doubt that none other than Kakabhushundi would know the subtle differences from one iteration to another. However, what interests me most is that none have given a detailed description of how future would be "the age of science and technology "... no one ever mentions that in details. Wonder why???

Answer (score 1):

The mention of Kakabhushundi seeing the Ramayana and Mahabharata multiple times is given in the Yoga Vasishtha. However there is no mention of there being different outcomes. This is either a mistranslation or misinterpretation somewhere. Quoting what the Yoga Vasishtha really says:

> राक्षसक्षतये विष्णोर्महीमवतरिष्यतः। अधुनैकादशं जन्म रामनाम्नो भविष्यति॥३०॥
>
> For the destruction of Raksasas, **this is the eleventh time that Lord Vishnu** who descends many times on earth, will take birth, under the appellation of Rama.
>
> वसुदेवगृहे विष्णोर्भुवो भारनिवृत्तये। अधुना षोडशं जन्म भविष्यति मुनीश्वर॥३२॥
>
> Oh sage, For eliminating the burden of the earth, now **Lord Vishnu’s sixteenth birth will take place** in the house of Vasudeva.
> -*Yoga Vasishtha, Nirvana Prakarana, [Chapter 22](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118566.html), verse 30-32*

The primary motive of Ramavatara was killing of Rakshasas troubling the earth and that of Krishnavatara was to release the earth from its burden of swarming Kshatriya armies. That said, if the purpose of the Avatara is not fulfilled there is no point of the avatara, which would mean that for the avatara to be successful- the outcomes would have to be killing of Rakshasas with king Ravana for Ramavatara and the elimination of almost all Kshatriya kings through various battles like the one at Kurukshetra. There can thus be no ‘other outcomes’.

Support for this is taken from the above verses of the Yoga Vasishtha itself where - **for the destruction of rakshasas** Ramavatara is about to happen for the 11th time. Meaning 10 times previously, Ravana has been defeated at the hands of Rama. Similarly Krishnavatara is happening for the 16th time **to relieve the earths burden**, which means that Jarasandha, Shalva, Paundraka, Duryodhana, Pralambabakadhenukadi have met their end 15 times previously and will again do so.

Now the Ramacharitmanas lists [various reasons for why Ramavatara happened](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48125), but the story each time is the same as is evident from the the verse given at the end of listing the various reasons:-

> हरि प्रेरित जेहिं कलप जोइ जातुधानपति होइ। सूर प्रतापी अतुलबल दल समेत बस सोइ॥
>
> By influence of Hari, in whichever Kalpa whoever becomes (Ravana), the king of the Rakshasas, courageous and strong, he lives with his group there only(talking of Lanka).
>  -*Ramacharitmanas Balakanda Doha 178*

When we say Kalapabheda Hari Charita Suhay Nana Bhaanti Munisanh Gaye, we are actually saying that in different Kalpas the same story of Hari is sung in different ways. Nowhere does it mean that the outcome is different.

Thus Ramayana Mahabharata have the same outcomes every time and this concept of different outcomes is a misinterpretation or mistranslation of the Yoga Vasishtha verses.