# Post Kalki Events and the Start of the World as we it taday

Tags: universe

What will happen post Kalki period ? Will all the events take place again, viz. Churning of the Ocean, Ramayana, Mahabharata, and so on.

Comment: Are you there if yes give my answer a green tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End of kaliyug, start of satyug events

> Having exterminated the thieves and robbers, Kalki(chakravarti samrath;avtar of shri hari) will, at a great
> ashwamedh yagya duly give away this earth to the Brahmanas.
>
> Mahabharat  Vana parva Section [CLXL](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7470.html)
>
> And when those terrible times of kaliyug will be over, the creation
> will begin anew. And men will again be created and distributed into
> the four orders beginning with Brahmanas. And about that time, in
> order that men may increase, Providence, according to its pleasure,
> will once more become propitious
>
> And then when the Sun, the Moon, and Vrihaspati will, with the
> constellation [Pushya](https://www.askganesha.com/nakshatra/pushya), enter the same sign, the Krita age will
> begin again.
>
> [Mahabharat vana parva ,Section CLXXXIX](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7469.html)

Events will happen again

From bhagvad gita

> यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत | अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं
> सृजाम्यहम् || 7||
>
> परित्राणाय साधूनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् | धर्मसंस्थापनार्थाय सम्भवामि
> ***युगे युगे || 8||***
>
> Whenever there is a decline in righteousness and an increase in
> unrighteousness, O Arjun, at that time I manifest Myself on earth. To
> protect the righteous, to annihilate the wicked, and to reestablish
> the principles of dharma ***I appear on this earth, age after age.***

So mahabharat and ramayan will happen again as avtars of shri hari come in every age.

To know more, [read](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11145)

But churning of ocean won't happen as

> Bhagavad Gita chapter 8 17-18 One day of ***Brahma (kalp)*** lasts a
> thousand cycles of the four ages (mahā yug) and his night also extends
> for the same span of time. The wise who know this understand the
> reality about day and night.
>
> At the advent of Brahma’s day, *all living beings emanate from the
> unmanifest source. And at the fall of his night, all embodied beings
> again merge into their unmanifest source.*

Means devtas are born at start of kalp then they won't require amrit in
every yug.

One [kalpa](https://cs.annauniv.edu/insight/Reading%20Materials/astro/sharptime/mahayugas.htm#:%7E:text=One%20Kalpa%20is%20said%20to,71%20*%2014%20%3D%20994%20yugas.) equals 71 * 14 = 994 yugas.

Hence, no churning of ocean

Comment: Thank you for the response.